# Templates - huge object file causes linker crash

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, arm, elf

I have a source file which extensively makes use of templates. 
I also have in that file explicit instantiations of different templates ... a lot of them.
This file is compiled as part of a static library. I compile this 
library on multiple platforms\for multiple architecture: Win x86, 
Linux x86 and Linux ARM. For the Linux builds I use different compilers 
so the resulting files(I'm talking here in context of the ELF file 
itself) are different: for GCC the resulting object file is 8.4MB in size 
and has a bit more than 40000 ELF sections; for the ARM compiler(armcc) 
the resulting file is 12.7MB in size and has more than 90000 ELF 
sections(!); in both cases I have debug information.

What happens is that at link time the ARM linker chokes and dies trying to 
link that huge object file in the static library. After some investigation it seems 
that it cannot handle object files with more than 65536 ELF sections in it(I still have 
to get a confirmation from the compiler vendor, though ... or I'm doing 
something completely and utterly wrong). The solution I found to that is splitting the 
file into multiple smaller files(it's structure and what was inside allowed for that).

The question(s): is there any other alternative solution? Would it be 
possible for the compiler to generate extra code in the object file(in the context of the templates) 
before the linking phase?

Comment: "An unsigned short should be enough for everyone, no one will ever have more than 65536 ELF sections..."

Answer (score 1):

With the ARM RVCT compiler (armcc), try adding --remove_unneeded_entities to the command line. This might or might not have much effect depending on which version of the compiler you are using, but its worth a try

Comment: I'm using the latest version of the compiler. The flag you suggested works for some files but not for all :), meaning the linker still crashes for some other files. I would have to split my files if I want to use the ARM tools ... don't know if I will do it though as GCC(both the x86 and the CodeSourcery one for ARM) handles the code perfectly. I opened a bug on the ARM support site but I'm not hoping for anything spectacular. I'm very dissapointed with the ARM tools right now and I think I might have thrown a lot of money out the window as this has been a week in Hell alongside the ARM tools

Comment: Hmmm, I guess the other thing you could try is the 64 bit ARM linker? I think the 64 bit linker has been available since RVCT4.1